# MYSQL Trigger over an attribute with default value

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have this trigger:

```
USE `PalestraDB`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `Lezione_BINS` BEFORE INSERT ON `Lezione` FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.Codice_Lezione = (SELECT max(Codice_Lezione) + 1 FROM Lezione WHERE CodCorso = NEW.CodCorso);
END
```

Defined on this table:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `PalestraDB`.`Lezione` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `PalestraDB`.`Lezione` (
`CodCorso` INT NOT NULL,
`Codice_Lezione` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
`Data` DATE NOT NULL,
`Orario` TIME NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`Codice_Lezione`, `CodCorso`),
 INDEX `fk_Lezione_Corso1_idx` (`CodCorso` ASC),
 CONSTRAINT `fk_Lezione_Corso1`
 FOREIGN KEY (`CodCorso`)
 REFERENCES `PalestraDB`.`Corso` (`Codice_corso`)
 ON DELETE CASCADE
 ON UPDATE CASCADE)
 ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

What I want to do is compute the "Codice_lezione" value, based on the primary key "CodCorso" and have something like this:

```
CodCorso 1 Codice_Lezione 1;
CodCorso 1 Codice_Lezione 2;
CodCorso 1 Codice_Lezione 3;
CodCorso 2 Codice_Lezione 1;
CodCorso 2 Codice_Lezione 2;
CodCorso 3 Codice_Lezione 1;
CodCorso 3 Codice_Lezione 2;
```

and so on... This was working fine without the default value, if I only added to the Codice_Lezione column the new number would be computed the right way.
But of course if I add another course (CodCorso represents the number of a course, Codice_Lezione the number of the lessons of the course), I'd have no value to find max(Codice_Lezione) and it would give me an error. So I thought "I'll just have it default to 1". This way, the first insertion work, I get CodCorso # and Codice_Lezione 1. The second one fails though, giving me error 1062, saying that key #-1 cor CodCorso-Codice_lezione already exist. (default to 0 does the same)

So how can I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a default, you can create a "BEFORE" trigger that sets the value to 0, and the "AFTER" trigger that you already have.

When inserting the first row, "before" trigger will set the value of Codice_Lezione to 0, and then "after" trigger will set it to 1.

With the second row, "before" trigger will set the value of Codice_Lezione to 0, and then "after" trigger will set it to 2. Etc.

Let me know if that doesn't work.